# unique array values

Tags: php

I have string of comma separated values.

```
1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,01633,4,4
```

I need to remove the duplicates, so I though of using

```
array_unique($str);
```

However, it returns no results. So I decided to output it to see what I have:

```
print_r($str);
// returns: 1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,01633,4,4
```

I'm a little lost. I checked if it is an array and I got true. Here's how that string is created:

```
$str = '1,2,3';

foreach ($a as $b) {
    $str.= ','.$b;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to an array, remove the repeat values, convert to string

```
$str = 'whatever';
$arr = explode( ',', $str );
$newArr = array_unique( $arr );
$newStr = implode( ',', $newArr );
```

Comment: I actually tested to see if it was an array: is_array($str) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array'; and got Array...

Comment: @santa, then skip lines 1-2 and use lines 3-4. You shouldn't be storing an array value in a variable named `$str`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = explode(',', $str); // create array
$newArray = array_unique($str); // then process
```

actually, though... just do your `array_unique()` on `$a` before the string is created.

```
$a = array_unique($a);
```

then...

```
foreach ($a as $b) { // and so on
```

Comment: Or in one line `$newArray = array_unique(explode(',', $str));` ^_^

Comment: I actually need it as a comma separated values in the end, just no duplicates... Do i have to implode it back then?

Comment: If you go with the first way I suggested above, you could then create a string with `implode(',', $newArray)`.

Answer (score 1):

Explode on comma, make unique, glue pieces back together:

```
$str = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $str)));
```